# Support for multi-line properties in Maven filtering?

Tags: filtering, maven

Is there a way to support multi-line values in a build.properties used by Maven's filtering mechanism?

I have several that are like this (they are the Base64-encoded version of a certificate, like the one below). Making it a single-line value is possible, but not that great when editing.

```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```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what is `build.properties`, but you definitely can use multi-line properties.
For instance:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
       ...
       <testProp>my\
multiline\
property</testProp>
```

And `test.txt` in resources

```
${testProp}
```

After filtering `test.txt` would look like:

```
my
multiline
property
```

Comment: This is definitely what I was after when Google brought me here :)

Answer (score 2):

For a more general solution, I finally used `${line.separator}` in the property value.

e.g.

```
    <project>
    ...
    <properties>
       ...
       <testProp>my${line.separator}
multiline${line.separator}
property</testProp>
```